# attaching position a div to a centered div relative to page

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

attempting to position a red div attached near to a centered div as shown in image below:
can you suggest me a css3 or jquery easy method ?

orange div is centered via style:{margin-left and margin-right auto}
I want just red div always shall be near to red div.
**and also red div TOP position should be fixed as where it is.not relative to orange div. (relative to webexplorer)**

[image]

Comment: I did edit my answer to make what you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSS3 needed in this case, if you know the dimension of the red div, you can do the following (as shown in this [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/adojam/1)):

```
.orange {

  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;

}

.red {

  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

}
```

If you don't know the dimension of the element, then the situation gets a bit trickier, as the child element will not overflow its parent, hence the dimension will always be **maximum the red div dimension.** In that case you will have to modify the CSS a bit and add some jQuery magic, like demonstrated in this other [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/adojam/2).

### CSS

```
orange {

  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: static;

}

.red {

  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var redWidth = $('.red').width();
  $('.red').css('left', -redWidth);

});
```

### Update

Since you updated your question, the answer needs to be updated as well: out of the top of my head, I can think of this solution (you can see it working [**here**](http://jsbin.com/adojam/4)):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $('.red').css('top', window.pageYOffset);

});
```

But perhaps there is a better CSS-only solution.

### Update #2

Ok, found a more elegant, CSS-only, solution, only if you know the width of the centered container, though. Hear this (and see it [**in action**](http://jsbin.com/adojam/5)):

```
.red {

  background-color: red;
  margin-left: -150px; // See note (1)
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

}
```

**(1)** This margin is calculated by halving the `width` of the orange element and adding the red one's own `width`. If you don't know red one's width, use the trick explained above under the section **Javascript**.

Comment: great! thank you.
wonderful answer ! exactly what Im looking for.you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the dimensions of the red block, you can place it inside the orange block and absolute position it to its width pixels to the left:

**See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v78df/)**

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFCE6B;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}

.orangeblock {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.redblock {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="orangeblock">
        <div class="redblock"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you *don't* know the dimensions of the red block, then you could still place it inside the orange block and do the positioning via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".redblock").css({position: "absolute", left: -$(".redblock").outerWidth()})
});
```

Comment: problem is this. I want top position is fixed (to explorer.not page)
so if page is scrolled to bottom the red div should stay as where it is.

Comment: @Mahn Actually the jQuery solution is not *completely* exact: the child red block will never overflow its parent dimension with this layout, hence **(a)** either it will stretch its parent to its dimension or **(b)** will be of the parent fixed dimension. To solve this issue see my answer.

Comment: @N.Ramos I updated my answer to meet your new requirement with jQuery.